# Each minimal normal subgroup of is contained in the center

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, nilpotence

Let $G$ be finite nilpotent. I want to show that each minimal normal subgroup of $G$ is contained in $Z(G)$ and has order $p$.

$$$$

We have that $Z(G)=\{g\in G\mid ga=ag , \ \forall a\in G\}$.

$$$$

$G$ is nilpotent iff $\exists$ a series of normal subgrousp $N_i$: 
$$1\leq N_1\leq N_2 \leq \dots \leq N_k=G$$ such that $N_{i+1}/N_i\subseteq Z(G/N_i)$, right?

$$$$

Could you give me some hints how we could show that each minimal normal subgroup of $G$ is contained in $Z(G)$ ?

Answer (score 6):

Suppose that $N$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $G$.

1.) Since $N$ is nontrivial and normal, $N ∩ Z(G)$ is nontrivial by nilpotency of $G$. Since $N ∩ Z(G)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, by minimality of $N$ we have $N = N ∩ Z(G)$, so $N\subseteq  Z(G)$.

2.) Since $N$ is in the center of $G$, every subgroup of $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, so $N$ contains no proper nontrivial subgroups. It follows that $N$ is abelian and simple, so it has prime order $p$.

Comment: We have that $G$ is nilpotent so $\exists N_i$, $N_i\trianglelefteq G$ with $N_{i+1}/N_i\subseteq Z(G/N_i)$, right? Why do we have that $N\cap Z(G)$ is nontrivial?

Comment: By the nilpotency of $G$. This is a result on nilpotent groups- see [this MSE-question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/616061/non-trivial-nilpotent-group-has-non-trivial-center) and [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127001/infinite-nilpotent-group-any-normal-subgroup-intersects-the-center-nontrivially). In particular, nilpotent groups have non-trivial center.

Comment: What exactly do we mean by **minimal** normal subgroup? A group $G$ is called nilpotent iff $\exists$ a series of normal subgroups $$1\leq N_1\leq N_2\leq \dots \leq N_k=G$$ such that $N_{i+1}/N_i\subseteq Z(G/N_i)$, right? Is the minimal subgroup in that case $N_1$ ?

Comment: No, not necessarily, see [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Minimal_normal_subgroup).

Comment: Is every abelian and simple group, a $p$ group?

Comment: Yes, it is isomorphic to the cyclic group $C_p$ of prime order, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186035/proof-that-all-abelian-simple-groups-are-cyclic-groups-of-prime-order).

Comment: Ah ok... Do we show that $N$ is abelian as follows? $$$$ We have that $N\subseteq Z(G)=\{g\in G\mid ga=ag, \forall a\in G\}$. So, for all $x,y\in N$ we have that $x,y\in Z(G)$ and $x,y\in G$. Therefore, $xy=yx$. That means that $N$ is abelian. $$$$ Could I improve something?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\;G\;$ is nilpotent, any non-trivial normal subgroup intersects non-trivially the center, and then for *minimal* non-trivial normal $\;N\lhd G\;$ we get

$$1<|N\cap Z(G)|\stackrel{\text{minim.}}\implies N\cap Z(G)=N\iff N\le Z(G)$$

Comment: We have that $G$ is nilpotent so $\exists N_i$, $N_i\trianglelefteq G$ with $N_{i+1}/N_i\subseteq Z(G/N_i)$, right? Why do we have that any non-trivial subgroup intersects non-trivially the center?

Comment: I really don't understand what you mean with your first question and what it has to do with your original one. As for the main claim in the answer: if we take the upper central series $\;1=Z_0\le Z_1\le\ldots\le Z_n=G\;$, then there is the smallest $\;k\;$ s.t. $\;N\cap Z_k=1\,,\,\,N\cap Z_{k+1}\neq1\;$ , so take $\;1\neq n\in N\cap Z_{k+1}\;$ , then  for all $\;x\in G\;$: $$[n,x]\in[N\cap Z_{k+1},\,G]\le [N\cap Z_k,\,G]=1\implies n\in Z(G)$$ since $\;[N,G]\le N\;$ (normality), and also $\;[Z_{k+1},G]\le Z_k\;$ (Central series).

Comment: I got stuck right now... What exactly do we mean by **minimal** normal subgroup? A group $G$ is called nilpotent iff $\exists$ a series of normal subgroups $$1\leq N_1\leq N_2\leq \dots \leq N_k=G$$ such that $N_{i+1}/N_i\subseteq Z(G/N_i)$, right? Is the minimal subgroup in that case $N_1$ ?

Comment: A normal subgroup $\;N\lhd G\;$ is minimal if it is not trivial ( i.e., $\;N\neq\{1\}\;$) and there is no *normal* subgroup $\;M\;$ of $\;G\;$ such that  $\;N\subsetneq M\subsetneq G\;$. Your definition of nilpotent is correct but a little odd, since it is usually defined by means of the upper central series, but it doesn't matter: the definition isn't connected with minimal/maximal subgroups, either normal or whatever.

Comment: Ah ok... Is the intersection $N\cap Z(G)$ a normal subgroup of $G$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar Of course. The intersection of any two normal subgroups is a normal subgroup.